# Make a ListView from rest API for Category only without duplication in Flutter

Tags: flutter, listview, dart, rest

```dart
[
  {
    "category": "Apple",
    "name": "Macbook Air"
  }, {
    "category": "Apple",
    "name": "Macbook Pro"
  }, {
    "category": "Microsoft",
    "name": "Surface"
  }, {
    "category": "Apple",
    "name": "iPad"
  }, {
    "category": "Microsoft",
    "name": "Windows"
  }, {
    "category": "Apple",
    "name": "Siri"
  }, {
    "category": "Microsoft",
    "name": "Office"
  }
]
```

I need to the common category into ListView from the Rest API data exampled above.

There is Apple & Microsoft are the category which common in the six data.

It's automatically done it.

Could you give a solution for this?

Comment: give an example expected list which you are expecting, then i could help you.

Comment: Welcome to stack**overflow**. Please try and get help with English, starting with `six data` (counting 7).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'dart:math';

const source = '''
{
    "data": [
        { "category": "Apple", "name": "Macbook Air" },
        { "category": "Apple", "name": "Macbook Pro" },
        { "category": "Microsoft", "name": "Surface" },
        { "category": "Apple", "name": "iPad" },
        { "category": "Microsoft", "name": "Windows" },
        { "category": "Apple", "name": "Siri" },
        { "category": "Microsoft", "name": "Office" }
    ]
}
''';

main(List<String> args) {
  final List data = jsonDecode(source)['data'];
  
  var mode = Map<String, int>();

  data.map<String>((e) => (e as Map)['category']).forEach((k) => mode[k] = (mode[k] ?? 0) + 1);

  var maxVal = mode.values.toList().reduce(max);
  var category = List<String>();

  mode.forEach((k, v) => v==maxVal ? category.add(k) : null);

  print(category.toString());
}
```

Comment: Other Way, we can use a unique dart function to implement for the above-requested need. But the above shared type also useful. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
  List getCategory(List data) {
    List list = [];
    for (var a in data) 
      if (!list.contains(a["category"]))
       list.add(a["category"]);
    return list;
  }
```

Comment: Other Way, we can use a unique dart function to implement for the above-requested need. But the above shared type also useful. thank you.